# How to add errors to Rails model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I tried to add an exception in the `before_save` method in a rails model, but in the view, no error message exists.

Model:

```
before_save do
    doing_some_stuff
    begin
      File.open('some_file', 'w+') do |file|
        if file.write(file_content)
          return true
        else
          return false
        end
      end
    rescue => e
      self.errors.add(:base, e.message) 
      return false
    end
```

View:

```
<%= @model.errors.any? %>
```

This is always false.

How do I add error messages to the model?

**EDIT:**

The problem was, I had a redirect after the update_attribute function instead of rendering the action again. Thx for help.

Comment: You should consider creating a method to handle your "before_create" logic. Like this `before_create :do_stuff`

Comment: How do you know that the File.open is raising an exception? Are you sure that its not just returning false from that else statement inside the open block?

Comment: i had logged out the error via logger.info to the logfile, the error raises in the rescue part

Comment: can you log `self.errors.inspect` in the rescue part as well ?

Comment: #<ActiveModel::Errors:0x007fce341218a8 @base=#<Model id: 13, [...]>, @messages={:base=>["Permission denied - /path/to/file"]}>

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You should be performing this on validation, not on `before_save`. By the time you get to the `before_save` callback, the record is assumed to be valid.

```
validate do
  doing_some_stuff
  begin
    File.open(some_file, 'w+') do |file|
      if !file.write(file_content)
        self.errors.add(:base, "Unable to write #{some_file}")
      end
    end
  rescue => e
    self.errors.add(:base, e.message)
  end
end
```

Comment: same problem as well, no error message in the view raised from the rescue part

Comment: What if i want to validate something before_save in above method ?